# I want to use two JSON requests to finish a vb.net object

Tags: json, vb.net, deserialization

I have one Vb.net object (below). It requires two JSON requests to complete the object. One request gives title and key while the other request gives me freeToPlay. How can I use both requests to create one object?

```
Public Class LeagueChampion
    Inherits LeagueObject
    'Public Property key As String
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property group As String
    Public Property tags As String()
    Public Property enemytips As String()
    Public Property allytips As String()
    Public Property blurb As String
    Public Property rankedPlayEnabled As Boolean
    Public Property botMmEnabled As Boolean
    Public Property botEnabled As Boolean
    Public Property active As Boolean
    Public Property freeToPlay As Boolean
End Class

  league_container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of LeagueChampionContainer)(rrm.returnFreeToPlayChampions("na"))
  league_container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of LeagueChampionContainer)(rrm.returnLeagueChampions("na"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use JavaScriptSerializer over DataContractJsonSerializer. The reasons are:

1. JavaScriptSerializer is faster over DataContractJsonSerializer.
2. DataContractJsonSerializer requires more code than JavaScriptSerializer for a simple serialization.